# Jmeter - While Load testing SOAP messages, its randomly skipping putting the SOAP header on a few messages

Tags: web-services, soap, jmeter

I am relatively new to Jmeter and exploring options to load test some SOAP services.

I did a test today with 10000 records in a csv file as an input to my Thread group.[image]

For the header I added SOAP Message Username token and SOAP message timestamp as we can see in the above screenshot.

Finally I have Content-Type text/xml;charset=UTF-8 in Header manager.

and csv config file as an input from the csv file. Out of 10000 SOAP messages, 65 failed and they don't have a header in the SOAP body which caused them to be rejected as shown in below screenshots.

[image]

Failed SOAP body is as below.

[image]

Failure response is as below.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><env:Header/><env:Body><env:Fault><faultcode>env:Server</faultcode><faultstring>Error on verifying message against security policy Error codes: 1001 1021 Error codes: 1001 1021</faultstring></env:Fault></env:Body></env:Envelope>
```

Successful SOAP response is as below.

[image]

I am not able to understand why the 65 messages out of 10000 got the headers skipped by Jmeter. Has anyone faced this issue and know why its happening?

Any inputs, insights or thoughts on this issue would be deeply appreciated.

Thanks for your time and patience.

Answer (score 1):

I have 1 input and 1 thought:

1. If you look at upper-right corner of JMeter GUI you will see 130 errors

   [image]

   so you should check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) and figure out what is the nature of these errors and what needs to be done to fix them, there is a chance it will resolve your issue as well
2. Don't use JMeter GUI for tests execution, it's for tests development and debugging only, when it comes to executing tests [you should run JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui). Also consider [disabling Listeners as they don't add any value and just consume valuable resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing/) which will definitely be required for "heavy" cryptographic operations

   More information: [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri T, the log definitely gave me the clue regarding the failure. It was due to the presence of & character in the data. I think Jmeter doesnt like it. May be there is an escape character for including & in the data. I will figure out. And also thanks for recommending the non-GUI mode and other tips. Much appreciated.

Comment: I ran the same program again, no failures.. :)